# How does [ ] work with a function, is the mean the function become and element?

Tags: r

I have a low triangle matrix:

```
> Mat1
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0    0    0
[3,]    3    3    0    0    0
[4,]    4    4    4    0    0
[5,]    4    1    1    3    0
```

`lower.tri` returns a matrix of logicals the same size of a given matrix with entries TRUE in the lower or upper triangle (R help).

Then lets

```
lowt <– lower.tri(Mat1)
xx <– Mat1[lowt]
xx
[1] 1 3 4 4 3 4 1 4 1 3
```

My question is how does Mat1[lowt] work? how do we use the function as an element by using [ ]?! what is the idea? any help please?

Comment: If you look at the 'lowt', it is a logical matrix.  So whereever there is TRUE values, it gets extracted by using `[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do we use the function as an element by using [ ]?!

`lowt` is not a function, but a boolean matrix, as you said yourself: 
`lowt <– lower.tri(Mat1)` saves the return variable of `lower.tri` in `lowt`; `Mat1[lowt]` therefore returns values from `Mat1`, by logical indexing - a widely used concept in R.